# Label not increasing in size

Tags: libgdx, label, scene2d

I want make my label of Scene2D larger. I have scaled and set width and height to 200 and higher and  it stays the same size.

Help? thanks.

Comment: You really need to show us what the code is that you have tried, as it stands right now, this question is unanswerable in IMHO.

Comment: Code added in asnwer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want a bigger font size?

You can do that by calling `lbl.font.setScale(yourFontSize);`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my bad english, it is my code:

```
    super(view, batch);

    LabelStyle lbl = new LabelStyle();
    lbl.font = new BitmapFont();
    lbl.fontColor = Color.WHITE;

    score = new Label("Score: ", lbl);
    score.setPosition(getCamera().viewportWidth / 2, getCamera().viewportHeight - 150);
    score.setSize(100, 100);
    score.setSize(200, 200);
    score.setScale(1.5f);
    score.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()); // update now
```

Comment: You should update your question instead of add your code as a answer. But hopefully i can help you with my posted answer..

Comment: Your welcome. Can you accept my answer so your question is closed?